# Script for Illustrator to adjust global color accross multiple documents

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator

Is there a way to change the color values of a global color in Illustrator with e.g. an javasript script in multiple documents? Let's say I have 100 documents which use all the same named global color and I want to adjust this one in all documents at the same time without having to open all documents manually.
I did not find a solution, yet, but maybe someone has an idea, how this could work?

Best, Hirschferkel

Comment: Of course it's possible. I'm doing it constantly. But it would be better if you clarify: what color space you're using (RGB, CMYK, Pantone, etc). How you named the color? The best way -- just to provide a couple your ai files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simplest case you can use this:

```
var folder = Folder("d:/_");
var files = folder.getFiles("*.ai");

for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {

    var doc = app.open(files[i]);
    var my_color = doc.swatches.getByName("color");

    my_color.color.spot.color.cyan    = 100;
    my_color.color.spot.color.magenta = 0;
    my_color.color.spot.color.yellow  = 100;
    my_color.color.spot.color.black   = 0;

    doc.save();
    doc.close();
}
```

It gets all `ai` files from folder `d:\_`. Changes the color with name `color` into the CMYK green (100,0,100,0). And saves all the files.

Comment: Is it possible to translate this javascript to a .ai script?

Comment: Illustrator can run js or jsx files natively (via Ctrl+12 or File > Scripts > Other Scripts...). Or you can drag and drop a jsx file into the Illustrator window with a mouse. Or you can run jsx scripts within any action ('Insert Menu Action... --> File > Scripts > Other Scripts...), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Updated version of Yuri Script, Just Add the ability to Select the *.ai Folder Selecting :

```
   // Get the folder containing the Illustrator documents
var folder = Folder.selectDialog("Select the folder containing the Illustrator documents");

// Check if a folder is selected
if (folder) {
  // Get all the files in the folder with .ai extension
  var files = folder.getFiles("*.ai");


for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {

    var doc = app.open(files[i]);
    var my_color = doc.swatches.getByName("YourColorName");

    my_color.color.spot.color.cyan    = 100;
    my_color.color.spot.color.magenta = 0;
    my_color.color.spot.color.yellow  = 0;
    my_color.color.spot.color.black   = 0;

    doc.save();
    doc.close();
    }
}
```